# Convert inline script for code behind

Tags: asp.net

How would I convert this inline script into something I can use in a code behind? I'd like to have the alert only show on the final else statement, before it deletes the account.

```
OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
```

Basically I want to have a confirm delete box show before deleting an account.

This is the click function in the code behind:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser userToDelete = Membership.GetUser(UserName.SelectedItem.Value);
    if (userToDelete == null)
    {
        message.Text = "User '" + UserName.SelectedItem.Value + "' Is Not Found";
    }
    else if (UserName.SelectedItem.Value == "Admin")
    {
        message.Text = "User '" + UserName.SelectedItem.Value + "' Cannot Be Deleted";
    }
    else
    {
        Membership.DeleteUser(UserName.SelectedItem.Value);
        message.Text = "User '" + userToDelete + "' Has Been Deleted";
        Response.Redirect("~/account/");
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot execute client script from serverside directly. So you could register this script but you would get the answer not before the page posts back the next time. You cannot compare it with a winforms application. The easiest would be to keep the client-side script, so if the user clicks on the delete-button he must confirm that he really wants to delete, otherwise the postback will be cancelled(`return false`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to throw out client side events during the execution of a server side function. You would instead have to take in the data, temporarily store it, and reload the page to display the confirmation. If they choose to continue, then the form would be resubmitted and the data that was temporarily stored earlier will now be saved.

Although, it may just be easier to prompt the user before they submit the data and just treat it like it is going to delete it. If it fails the logic checks, then simply alert the user that the action failed.